# Set Document mode for IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have created a one web application, it works fine in firefox and chrome but not in IE8.

I have tried following code in my header to set document mode :

```
<head>
<!-- meta tags -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8" />
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
<meta name="author" content="Web">
<meta name="description" content="Medical Services">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<!-- mobile -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2">
<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui">
</head>
```

I have tried this code but this not work. If i manually choose document mode "IE8 Standards" in IE using developer tool than its works fine. But i want to set "IE8 Standards" as default document mode.
How can i do this? Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `X-UA-Compatible` tag will not work as expected when the website is running on your localhost, or on another machine on your local network. Additionally, the tag shows up twice in your code, when it should only be listed once.

Remove one of the tags, and if it still doesn't work as expected, you will need to set this tag on the server instead.

If your website runs ASP.NET, put this in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE8" /> <!-- or other value of your choice -->
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If your website runs PHP, place this on the first line of your page:

```
<?php
header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE8');
?>
<!-- or other value of your choice -->
```

or if your site is running in Apache, set it in your .htaccess file to enable it globally:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
  # Don't send it for non-HTML content
  <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svg|svgz|ttf|vcf|webm|webp|woff|xml|xpi)$">
    Header unset X-UA-Compatible
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i have develope this site in php. So where to find find "web.config" ?

Comment: Web.config is only used by asp.net applications. Updated my answer to show how to do it in PHP.

Comment: i have also try "
header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=8');"

Comment: Hmmm. Can you inspect the HTTP headers to make sure that it is being sent? Also, what does your `DOCTYPE` declaration look like?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">

Comment: It might be your DOCTYPE that is causing it to trip up then, What happens if you change it to `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54792/discussion-between-s4suryapal-and-elgavilan).

Comment: i have tried with "<!DOCTYPE html>" but it still doesn't work